# Bluetooth is still active on Samsung S4 after switching it off

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

Im creating an app that connects to a bluetooth device in order to control it. When the user switches bluetooth off using the system settings, the bluetooth stack notifies my app about the disconnect (calling BluetoothGattCallback.onConnectionStateChange()).

This works as expected on many Android devices (such as HTC Nexus 9 Android 5.1.1) but not on all (such as Samsung S4). On some Android devices the bluetooth connection is still valid and the connected bluetooth device can still be controlled by my app. It looks like the system actually ignores the setting done by the user.

I know how to register for events, triggered by changes of the bluetooth adapter state and I can add the code to disconnect from the controlled device on such an event. But this is odd. I will have to consider this state in many locations in the code. I'd expect the system to disconnect and shutdown bluetooth, if the user does so through the system settings UI, just like some Andoid devices do.

So my questions are. Why does the system in some cases not shut down bluetooth as expected and is there a way to *configure* the system (or my application) to behave as expected. Are there some properties that need to be set at the involved objects (BluetoothDevice, BluetoothAdapter, ...)?

Some more details:
Even if bluetooth is already switched off when the app starts, the app will connect to the device via bluetooth just as if bluetooth was never deactivated. Isn't this kind of security isse, too?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite strange problem, have you try another way to monitor the status of Bluetooth? I have used a receiver for ALC_DISCONNECT and ALC_CONNECTED, it works well.

```
 <intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED" />
    <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Well, this is the option I indicated by my 3rd paragraph _"...I know how to register for events ... and I can add the code to disconnect from the controlled device on such an event... But this is odd..."._ Isn't it?